# how can I prevent zimbra to send email as root user?

Tags: zimbra

Zimbra is working on Ubuntu 12.04 and there are some system users (i.e. root). Zimbra is trying to send email to itself (root@some.domain) and hangs on mailq, then prevents other mail's distribution. But I cannot stop it from sending email. I tried to use aliases file as root: /dev/null but does not work. What else can be done to do prevent this?

Comment: What exactly zimbra is sending? Mail with stats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`root@yourdomain.com` is default account on many Linux distributions, and just should exists.

On that mail you are getting for example information about **failed cron jobs** (jobs that write to stderr) and other quite important things.

What I suggest:

- create alias to Your main administrator account `root@yourdomain.com` in Zimbra admin panel
- maybe creating `~/.forward` file will be an option? [here](http://www.feep.net/sendmail/tutorial/intro/forward.html) is first tutorial found on Google